# Trying to rename multiple.csv files using data contained within the file

Tags: r, excel, csv, dataframe, for-loop

A machine I use spits out .csv files named by the time. But I need them named after the plate they were read from, which is contained within the file.

I created list of files:

```
files <- list.files(path="", pattern="*.csv")
```

I then tried using a for-loop to first create a data frame from each file containing the 1st row only, then to create a variable from the relevant piece of data, (the desired name), and then renaming the files.

```
for(x in files)
{
  y <- read.csv(x, nrow = 1, header = FALSE, stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
  z <- y[2, 2]
  file.rename(x, z)
}
```

It didn't work. After 7 hours of trying (new to R) I am here. Please give simple advice, I have basically zero R experience.

Comment: If you have set `nrow = 1` how do you expect to get `y[2, 2]` (2nd row value)? Is the value you want a column name?

Comment: *"It didn't work."* (argggg) Besides the file not being renamed, were there any indications or output? Errors or warnings? For now, please accept Rui's answer. For your next question, it will help if you provide something self-contained and reproducible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following `for` loop does what the question asks for if the new filename is the *second column header* value.

If it is not, change `nmax` to the appropriate column number.

```
fls <- list.files(pattern = '\\.csv')

for(f in fls){
  x <- scan(file = f, what = character(), nmax = 2, nlines = 1, sep = ',')
  g <- paste0(x[2], '.csv')
  file.rename(f, g)
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rui, this is fantastic. Works perfectly, exactly as requested.